# Issue with EmberJS link-to helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a simple restaurant menu and I have a code like this which works fine:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <h1> Categories </h1>
      {{#each}}
        {{#link-to "dish" this.id}} {{name}} {{/link-to}} 
        </br>
      {{/each}}
      {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

It works, but I still can't figure out why I should pass `this.id` to the parameter of a `link-to`. Inititaly I've passed just `this` to the helper and it didn't work (WHY?) and only after some time of debugging I made it work with `this.id`.

So the question is, why it works with `this.id` and doesn't work with `this`? All examples I've seen so far always used `this` so is it a good approach to use `this.id`? Please explain!

Here is the full code http://jsbin.com/AcoHeNA/44/

Comment: Looking through your code, I see that you are iterating through your collection of categories, then passing `this` to the `{{link-to}}` helper. That shouldn't work! `DishRoute` expects a `Dish` model, you are passing a `Category` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `this.id` because the `{{link-to}}` helper can take:

- The name of a route. In this case it would be `"dish"`.
- At most one model for each dynamic segment.
- An optional title which will be bound to the `a` title attribute.

When you pass a model to the route, it doesn't fetch model data from a remote server, it takes "as is" and passes it to the controller.

If you pass an id to the helper, it makes sure to run the route's model hook with the id as an argument, retrieving the model's data.

What happens is that in your code you were passing `this` which is a `Category` model. The `DishRoute` is for `Dish` models so it just doesn't work.

It works if you pass `this.id` because it is an integer and Ember will fetch a `Dish` that happens to have the same `id` that whatever `Category` instance `this` is set to.

In doubt, read the official docs (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/)